# Android delphi. Error in system.startupcopy when compiling in Rio 10.3.2

Tags: android, delphi, startup

I can compile an APK for Android in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. However, when I compile it in Delphi 10.3.2 Rio, I obtain the following error:

> [DCC Error] System.StartUpCopy.pas(212): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ExcludeEmpty'

The error in in the last line of this code:

```pascal
procedure ProcessDeployedFiles(const LAssetManager:PAAssetManager; LFilesStr: string);
var
  I: integer;
  FileName: string;
  AFiles: TArray<string>;
begin
  AFiles := LFilesStr.Split([string(#13#10)], ExcludeEmpty);
```

Yes, the APK at the startup is copying some files.

Comment: You're including an older version of System.StartupCopy. In 10.3.2, the line is: AFiles := LFilesStr.Split([string(#13#10)], TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);

Comment: Also I don't understand this comment: "Yes, the apk at the startup is copying some files." How can it be, if your application does not compile?

Comment: Thanks Dave! I will update the file. The apk complies in 10.2